# macro that prints visible area after filter in excel

Tags: excel, vba, printing, filter

I have a macro that filters the table based on `column A` values. Now I want to print **only** the visible rows after the filter, but sadly it prints all of the rows including the top and bottom rows that were hidden during the filter.

In my sheet, there are data from `Column A:I`, but the print area should only be `Columns C:I` - visible rows after filter.

Here are the codes that I've tried so far that didn't work:

Code 1:

```
  ActiveSheet.PageSetup.printarea = Range("C3:I81000").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Code 2:

```
 Dim lastrow As Long
 lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(lastrow, 9)).Select
 ActiveSheet.PageSetup.printarea = Selection.Address
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: If I have a set of filtered data, only the data that is **visible** is printed - and I can't even find any options that would allow me to print the hidden data.  (So that means the PrintArea can remain as C3:I81000 without having to worry about selecting only visible cells.)  I would be intrigued to find out how you are managing to print the hidden stuff.

Comment: I think there were some extra formatting in some of the rows below, so even if they are empty they were considered used rows. So I deleted those rows and tweaked CODE 1. It's finally working! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this code worked! :) Thanks to all!

```
  ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("C3:I" & lastrow).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need the code for, I just confirmed that the following snippet works:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Range("C3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Selection.Address
    'ActiveSheet.PrintOut
Range("C3").Select
End Sub
```

Please activate the "PrintOut" row only if you want the command to be send to the printer.

For some reason. the "Selection" for rows works better for hidden/filtered cells, than other options of selection rows.

Hope that helps
Best
seulberg1

Comment: Thanks for replying. So I tried your code and the problem is it only highlights the cells with data. My list has random spaces everywhere so this didn't work correctly, it only selected a portion of the list. I think what I need is to know the top row number and the last row number after the filter, then I can use those values for the print area range.. does that make sense?