# Print specific column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have one file with column look below

```
No    Name    Address         Status

1     Indah   Bali            Single
2     Joki    Lombok          Married
3     Janu    Muara Basung    Married
```

I need to print specific column where only someone with Status 'Married' will print, and others wont. How can I do that?
Things I need show below.

```
No    Name    Address         Status

1     Joki    Lombok          Married
2     Janu    Muara Basung    Married
```

Comment: Filter then view this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862244/macro-that-prints-visible-area-after-filter-in-excel)
If you don't know how to filter look up "Filter" in SO

Comment: You can also view this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47194135/vba-autofilter-columns-and-printing-visible-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

<sub><sup>1. Select the desired column headings</sup></sub>
<sub><sup>2. Click AutoFilter</sup></sub>
<sub><sup>3. Filter columns as desired</sup></sub>
<sub><sup>4. Select column to print</sup></sub>
<sub><sup>5. File > Print > Print Selection > Print</sup></sub>