# How to set print area to last visible text in row and column?

Tags: vba

Worksheet has 100 rows and about 150 columns.

At any given time, only 20/40 of these will be visible.

CTRL+ UP for rows = 100 (row)

Ctrl+LEFT = CS (column)

Is there a way to VBA set print area for only visible rows.columns?

I can't figure out the dynamic name range print area function but thank you in advance.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("B:H").Address
```

This is an adjacent set print area that works, Range would be A1: to last row/column that has visible data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38878816/1521579

Comment: I saw that one and converted/tried to convert my formula for it. I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

See how I find the last column and row and then build the range

```
Public Sub PrintRange()
    
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = targetSheet.Cells(1, targetSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Dim printRange As Range
    Set printRange = targetSheet.Range("A1", targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    
    targetSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = printRange.Address
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I added the following: targetSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = printRange.address

Comment: This works on the rows, but not on the columns but i'm 10 steps from where I was

Comment: Fixed it. In what row does the data begins?

Comment: Row 1 is the first column for data

Comment: If you debug the code with F8 key, what prints ? PrintRange.Address?

Comment: It printpreviews the code fine, all the visible rows are identified but they are about 4 visible columns that aren't included

Comment: When you’re in this line: targetSheet.PageSetup... go to inmediate window write ? PrintRange.Address and hit enter

Comment: I confirmed this is already on my code. it's still not setting printing area of the visible columns

Comment: But is the range address correct? Not the syntax, but the output

Comment: The range address is correct, I don't know difference of syntax/output. It sets the range correctly for rows, not for columns

Comment: Check Debug.Print here https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code